# AWS policy error -- Number of resources is greater than maximum allowed

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-cloudformation, aws-policies

Below is my code to add policy but not sure what's wrong as its givng error while running for cloud formation as error occurred (ValidationError) when calling the ValidateTemplate operation: Template format error: Number of resources, 201, is greater than maximum allowed, 200\n", "stdout": "", "stdout_lines": []}

```
AWSTemplateFormatVersion: 2010-09-09
Description: ''
Resources:
  PSEJenkinsS3Policy:
    Type: 'AWS::IAM::ManagedPolicy'
    Properties:
      ManagedPolicyName: pse-jenkins-s3-policy
      PolicyDocument:
        Version: '2012-10-17'
        Statement:
          - Effect: Allow
            Action:
            - s3:GetObject
            - s3:ListBucket
            - s3:ListAllMyBuckets
            - s3:PutObject
            - s3:PutObjectTagging
            Resource:
            - arn:aws:s3:::pase-*/*

Outputs:
  PSEJenkinsS3PolicyOutput:
    Value: !Ref PSEJenkinsS3Policy
    Export:
      Name: PSEJenkinsS3Policy
```

Comment: There is nothing wrong with the template. The error is due to something else.

Comment: When I run `aws cloudformation validate-template` on that template, it works fine. How are you doing the validation?

Comment: Hi, are creating this as a new stack with no nesting?

Answer (score 1):

All is ok... but CloudFormation have limit of number of resources per stack of 200 resources. Look here https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/cloudformation-limits.html

Description: Maximum number of resources that you can declare in your AWS CloudFormation template.

Value: 200 resources

Solution: break your stack in two...

Answer (score 0):

It means exactly what the error says, your only allowed 200 resources per cloudformation stack [AWS Docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/cloudformation-limits.html). If your getting this error, with the above template, I can only assume you are using a compiler which is combining your modularised smaller yaml resources into a single file when deploying the cloudformation stack?